# Mobile Safari selectbox when user clicks done

Tags: iphone, ios, safari, drop-down-menu

I am making a website that works on iphone. I have a selectbox and want to call a function when user clicks "done" button.

[image]

```
<select>
<option value="value1">Value1</option>
<option value="value2">Value2</option>
<option value="value3">Value3</option>
<option value="value4">Value4</option>
</select>
```

I know "onchange" event but it is not helping because onchange is fired when only selected value is changed. But I want to call a function when user clicks "done" button.

Comment: I am having the same problem. jQuery's .change event handler doesn't pick up the done button submission.  Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how I couldn't think onblur:

```
<select onblur="thefunctionname()">
<option value="value1">Value1</option>
<option value="value2">Value2</option>
<option value="value3">Value3</option>
<option value="value4">Value4</option>
</select>
```